# Why does soup.select_one('#TranslationsHead') only extract part of the content?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the element `<div id="TranslationsHead">...</div>` in this [url](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/love). Here is the structure of it.

[image]

I use below code

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/love'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get(url, headers = headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


soup.select_one('#TranslationsHead')
```

and its result is `<div id="TranslationsHead"><span id="TranslationsTitle">Translations</span></div>`.

Could you please explain why it does not capture `<span id="LangBar"> ... </span>`?

Comment: Have you verified that the HTML loaded by `requests` looks like that? Because any Javascript running after a browser loads a page might well have made alterations that are not part of the original source of the page.

Comment: Looking at the HTML response, there is no `<span id="LangBar">` there. BeautifulSoup can't find what is not served as HTML at the start.

Comment: Oh I see @MartijnPieters. Do you have any suggestion to run `request` after all javascript completes?

Comment: requests is not a browser, it only handles HTTP requests and responses. Note that I don't see a `LangBar` id in my browser inspector either, but perhaps it is being filtered out by an ad blocker or some such. You want a headless browser (pypuppeteer, selenium, requests-html, the latter uses pypuppeteer under the hood), to run JavaScript for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @MartijnPieters! I'm trying `requests-html`.